# PHP Directory Iterator Constructor Issue

Tags: php

I am new to using the PHP Directory Iterator.

My understanding is if I do:

```
 $dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname("/var/wwwphp"));
```

Then

```
$dir->getPath();
```

should be /var/wwwphp and I can start using it in that folder. But instead, getPath just gives me /var. Furthermore, if I iterate over the files, it gives me all the files in /var and not /var/wwwphp.

Why can I not go straight into the wwwphp folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/var/wwwphp');
```

`dirname` explicitly removes the last part of the string, the `DirectoryIterator` only ever gets to see `/var` if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you check up the dirname documentation you will see that it "Returns parent directory's path"

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php